# Subclassing existing model in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm not sure why this isn't working, since it seems to be exactly what the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) tells me to do.

I want to be able to subclass the built-in User model so that I can add extra fields to it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Person(User):
    my_extra_field = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #...
```

This seems rather simple, and the way I understand it, all the methods of User should be available to Person. However, calling

```
user = Person.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
```

in the django shell results in an error.

Is this just a quirk of the shell (I'm using iPython), or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

You need to include the UserManager().  Import the User, UserManager and set the UserManager() to the variable objects in your Person class.